# Error applying dictionary to table view in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary

I'm very new to developing in Objective C and am trying to figure out why I'm getting an error with my NSDictionary when trying to apply it to a table view. I'm getting the error "Expected method to read array element not found on object of type 'NSDictionary*". Does anyone know what that means, or how I would go about fixing it? I've included the model where I'm having the issue.

UPDATED:
The statement getting flagged is:

```
NSDictionary *conversation = self.data[indexPath.row];
```

Thanks!

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ConversationTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"conversationCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Get data from array at position of the row
    NSDictionary *conversation = self.data[indexPath.row];

    // Apply the data to each row
    cell.conversationRecipients.text = [conversation valueForKey:@"recipients"];
    cell.conversationPreview.text = [conversation valueForKey:@"last_message"];
    cell.conversationTime.text = [conversation valueForKey:@"last_thread_post_short"];

    //Set conversation thumbnail
    [cell.conversationThumbnail sd_setImageWithURL:[conversation valueForKey:@"sender_avatar"]];

    return cell;
}
```

Here's where I'm setting self.data:

```
// Successful Login
            // Create the URL from a string.
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"URLISHERE"]];


            NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60];

            [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
            [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

            // Prepare for the response back from the server
            NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
            NSError *error = nil;

            // Send a synchronous request to the server (i.e. sit and wait for the response)
            NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
            NSError *serializeError;
            id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&serializeError];

            // Get response
            self.data = json;
            NSLog(@"%@", self.data);

            // Reload data after Get
            [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Well, it would be nice to know what statement is being flagged.

Comment: But one suspects that `self.data` is an NSDictionary and you're attempting to index it with an integer.

Comment: How would I go about resolving that?

Comment: Well, first see if `self.data` really *is* an NSDictionary.  Then, if it is, figure out how it should be accessed, since you clearly can't "index" it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.data` needs to be of type `NSArray` not `NSDictionary` then it will work.